# How to add additional iOS simulator for flutter?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter

Currently I'm using Android Studio with Flutter's plugin. And I had no issues with running app on only available iOS simulator. Still, I want to add additional simulators to have possibility test different screen sizes. Please advice.

```
% flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-UA)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

% flutter devices
1 connected device:

iPhone 11 Pro Max • A4A8A03E-5529-498A-9481-A1DFEBA56524 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the iOS Simulator open, go to the top tabs Hardware > Device > iOS 13.3 (Or other version number) > (Whichever secondary version of the Simulator you'd like to open).  Normally this does not close down the original version of the simulator, so you can run different versions simultaneously.